# Issue adding javascript to a form using addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I have a form:

```
 <form method="post" name="Form1" action="default.asp" onsubmit="return processField();">

    <input type="hidden" name="hiddentext1">


    <input type="text" name="text1">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button1">
</form>
```

And what I want is to call `ProcessField` function on the submit of the form. I know that `ProcessField` function works fine - tested it using an inline call. But now I want to attach the event via JavaScript. Below is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.addEventListener){
        window.addEventListener('load', attachFormSubmit, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent){
        window.attachEvent('onload', attachFormSubmit );
}

function attachFormSubmit(){
    theForm = document.getElementById("Form1");
    alert("attaching form submit");
    if (theForm.addEventListener){          
            theForm.addEventListener('submit', CleanUpEID, false);
        } else if (theForm.attachEvent){            
            theForm.attachEvent('onsubmit', CleanUpEID);
        }

}

function ProcessField()
{
    alert("processing field");

    if (this.text1.value == '') 
    {
        alert ("Please enter the value")
        this.text1.focus()
        return false
    }

    this.hiddentext1.value = this.text1.value;

    // Disable button
    with ($('button1')) {
        value = "Processing ...";
        disabled = true;
    }


    return true;    
}   

</script>
```

I have two issues with the above script:

- it attaches the event to the form multiple times - every time page reloads. I suspect there is a better place for my code but cannot figure it out.
- Keyword "this" in `processField` function comes up undefined. It works fine if I replace "this" with form name, but I was wondering what needs to be  done in order for keyword "this" to work in this case.

I'd really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.
Thanks.

Comment: Is action="default.asp" on a IIS-server?

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT

> OP had a series of questions that involve some fundamental concepts of JavaScript. I have provided some links that will hopefully answer those questions. See the end of this post.

Rewrote the code to demonstrate it actually works with a [test server](http://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php). With the syntax errors, you'd never get it working. The biggest error is you call `processField()` but you define a function called `ProcessField()`, JavaScript is case-sensitive.

In order to function for your purposes, you'll have to change the form's `action` of course. I had to validate it's input for a min of 5 and a max of 15 alphanumerics due to the test server's limits, so you'll want to change that as well probably.

> 1. it attaches the event to the form multiple times - every time page reloads. I suspect there is a better place for my code but cannot figure it out

You are adding/attaching the eventListener/Handler to the window which makes your submit event global, plus you didn't provision any way to prevent default behavior, so any form and form elements that by default are triggered by a submit event will popup on the event chain.  I added the eventListener to the form and then used [`stopPropagation();`](http://jsforallof.us/2014/07/08/epreventdefault-estoppropagation/) to prevent any unintentional triggering during the bubbling phase.

> 2. Keyword "this" in processField function comes up undefined. It works fine if I replace "this" with form name, but I was wondering what needs to be done in order for keywrod "this" to work in this case.

See explanation above concerning the typo of `processField`.*

Btw, I didn't bother adding the cross-browser crap [`attachEvent` because IE8 is dead, and that 1% of the world can use IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=addeventlistener). If you want to cater to that 1% just apply `attachEvent` as you did in your code.

http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/34775593.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>34775593</title>
</head>

<body>


    <form method="post" id="Form1" name="Form1" action="http://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php/so_post">

        <input type="hidden" id="hiddentext1" name="hiddentext1">


        <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" placeholder="Submit 5 to 15 alphanumerics">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button1">
    </form>
    <p>Once post is submited, server's response is returned with value of #hiddentext1 and #text1</p>
    <div class="serverData">
        <a href="http://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php/data.php/so_post">Server-side Results</a>
    </div>

    <script>
        var form = document.getElementById('Form1');
        var htxt = document.getElementById('hiddentext1');
        var btn = document.getElementById('button1');

        form.addEventListener('submit', processField, false);

        function processField(e) {

            var txt = document.getElementById('text1');
            var str = txt.value;
            var alnum = str.length;
            alert("processing field");

            if (alnum < 5 || alnum > 15) {
                alert("Please enter a value of 5 to 15 alphanumeric values ");
                txt.focus();
                return false;
            }

            htxt.value = str;

            // Disable button
            this.setAttribute('disabled', true);
            this.value = "Processing ...";

            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### References

[`addEventListener()`](http://javascript.info/tutorial/introduction-browser-events#handlers-assignment-by-w3c-standard)

[Bubbling & capturing](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing)

[Loading](http://javascript.info/tutorial/onload-ondomcontentloaded)

[`<script>`](http://javascript.info/tutorial/adding-script-html)

[Getting elements](http://javascript.info/tutorial/searching-elements-dom#methods)

Comment: just FYI, the type has nothing to do with it, since it was only a type when I was typing the code into stackexchange, on my actual page the is no typo

Comment: Oh, and I was not going to down vote your answer in any case:) Quite the contrary

Comment: Btw, your code won't work because form.addEventListener('submit', processField, false); gets called before window loads

Comment: On the contrary, it works here: http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/34775593.html anything loading before the [window load event is not only possible but desired](http://stackoverflow.com/a/588048/2813224).

Comment: *just FYI, the type has nothing to do with it, since it was only a type when I was typing the code into stackexchange, on my actual page the is no typo* That's great, but it's not my responsibility to ensure that you type accurately nor could I have the knowledge of the real source in question. I can only go by what you provide. When I post a question or answer, I go over it at least once if not twice over again for any typos, grammatical, and even syntactical errors (at least the ones I'm capable of recognizing myself).   .

Comment: what happens with your code is document.getEelementById returning null because elements on the page are not loaded yet

Comment: Ok, first off let's establish **ONE** thing first: review http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/34775593.html Please verify that it indeed functions.